# How to access and mount an SMB Share via Command Line on Mac

Tags: macos, silent-installer

I want to extract dmg file from smb share drive and want to perform silent installation on mac machine .

I tried

```
$ mount_smbfs //'domain;username'@smb://a/b/c.dmg ~/local_folder
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not general OS/networking problems.

Comment: hi @MarcB shouldn't it be considered for bash scripting ?

Comment: that's not scripting. that's just typing in a command.